# Negating "jam" (i.e. to not already have done something)

Tags: adverbs, word-order

"jam ne" means "no longer" (like "ne ... plu") instead of "already not". But then how would one express the negation of just "jam"? That is to say, how to say that one has *not* already done something.

For example, if one already did something...

> I {have done}/{already did} it.
>   Mi jam faris ĝin.

But then what about...

> I {have not already done}/{did not already do} it.

I can imagine something like "mi ne jam faris ĝin", but I do not know if it would mean something else, like "jam ne" does, or if it would be understood differently.

Comment: A more common way to express "not already" in English in many contexts is AFAIK "not yet".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kelkaj uzas *ne jam* same kiel *ankoraŭ ne*. Tio ne malĝustas, sed estas iel evitinda.

[Jen klarigo](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/e-vortecaj_vortetoj/tempaj/jam.html#i-e5j) en PMEG.

Fine de la ligita klarigo (citilojn aldonis mi):

> Zamenhof tial prave konsilis, ke oni evitu "ne jam" uzante anstataŭe
>   "ankoraŭ ne", kaj plej multaj sekvas tiun konsilon.

Do:

> Mi ankoraŭ ne faris tion.

Notu ke la signifo de "jam ne" estas tute alia:

> Jam ne pluvas = Ne plu pluvas.